# How to prevent recursive with from full table scan in the start statement

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, query-optimization

I have a tree database structure with id and parent_id, and want to create a view which returns all superior for a given child id. 
It always results in a execution plan with a full table scan.

Adding hints or calculate statistics did not help.
The issue is reproducible even with a view records.
If I add the start condition direct into the start statement, the index is used and performance is good.

```
-- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0


CREATE TABLE t AS (
  SELECT   10 parent_id,   1 child_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  100 parent_id,  10 child_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL parent_id, 100 child_id FROM dual 
);


CREATE INDEX child_idx ON t (child_id);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW parents_v AS
WITH recu(
  start_id, child_id, parent_id
)
AS(
  -- start 
  SELECT 
     child_id start_id, child_id, parent_id
  FROM  t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
      recu.child_id, pre.child_id, pre.parent_id
  FROM  recu, t pre
  WHERE recu.parent_id = pre.child_id
)
SELECT * FROM recu;
```

Query to test index:

```
  SELECT * FROM t WHERE child_id = 1;
```

Explain plan:

```
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR);

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |           |       |       |     2 (100)|          |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T         |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CHILD_IDX |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Result Ok,index CHILD_IDX is used

Query to test recursion:

```
SELECT * FROM parents_v WHERE start_id = 1;
```

Explain plan:

```
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR);
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                 | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                          |      |       |       |     7 (100)|          |
|*  1 |  VIEW                                     |      |     6 |   234 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION ALL (RECURSIVE WITH) BREADTH FIRST|      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                      | T    |     3 |    78 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    HASH JOIN                              |      |     3 |   156 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     RECURSIVE WITH PUMP                   |      |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | T    |     3 |    78 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Result Not Ok,index CHILD_IDX is *not* used, always a full table scan is done.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? I tried this on 11.0.2.3 and the explain plan shows it used the index: `|   6 |      INDEX FULL SCAN                      | CHILD_IDX |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |`. Which, incidentally, highlights the fact that you Explain Plan examples aren't run against your posted code (index name is different).

Comment: Thx for the answer. I updated the index name later, just corrected it above. Interesting that You have and index full scan, shouldn’t it be a range scan. It looks like the main problem is that the system does not know that the start_id of the view is equal to the child_id used in the first select of the recursion.

Comment: Full Index Scan doesn't surprise me: Oracle doesn't know how many parents the starting child has, so it assumes the most efficient approach is to read the whole index and assembled the graph in memory. With a much larger table (and hence index) the optimizer might well take a different tack.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not possible to tell the DB that a column of a recursion has an one to one relation to the "start select" of the recursion. The only workaround I found is using a select statement with parameters, instead of using a view. 
In the select statement the start_id constraint can be added direct to the "start select".

### View and star_id_parameter (bad execution time)

DB builds up the complete datastruture in memory and filters at the end.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW parents_v AS
WITH recu(
  start_id, child_id, parent_id
)
AS(
  -- start 
  SELECT 
     child_id start_id, child_id, parent_id
  FROM  t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
      recu.child_id, pre.child_id, pre.parent_id
  FROM  recu, t pre
  WHERE recu.parent_id = pre.child_id
)
SELECT * FROM recu;


SELECT * 
FROM parents_v 
WHERE start_id = start_id_parameter;
```

### star_id_parameter in the start select of the recursion (fast execution)

DB uses index and only requests the view records in the path of the tree.

```
WITH recu(
  start_id, child_id, parent_id
)
AS(
  -- start 
  SELECT 
     child_id start_id, child_id, parent_id
  FROM  t
  -- CHANGE start_id CONSTRAINT ADDED
  WHERE child_id = &start_id_parameter
  --
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
      recu.child_id, pre.child_id, pre.parent_id
  FROM  recu, t pre
  WHERE recu.parent_id = pre.child_id
)
SELECT * FROM recu;

-- CHANGE NO VIEW ANY MORE
-- SELECT * 
-- FROM parents_v 
-- WHERE start_id = start_id_parameter;
```